# How can I connect 12.4 to the Internet with WEP key?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, security

I have Ubuntu and I want to know how can I connect to the Internet using my WEP key for my wireless.

I tried too many times but it doesn't work. I have my wireless password but it doesn't work too.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: While your WiFi AP (access point) settings may allow for use of **WEP**, **WPA**, or **WPA2**, only WPA2 provides **any** security.  ***You should not be using WEP, unless no other option is supported.***

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused.  A WEP key is a security code used on some Wi-Fi networks.  It is usually  a set of hex numbers 10 or 26 digits long.  A "wireless password" might mean you are using WPA encryption.  check out how to reset your router from the manual that came with it.  Usually this involves pressing a small button on the back of the router labeled "RESET" for several seconds then using the default password and username to set up your security--good luck!